# Why does ebtables-restore fail when loading output from ebtables-save?

Tags: linux-networking, ebtables

See:

```
%sudo ebtables-save
# Generated by ebtables-save v1.0 on Fri Mar  8 01:06:56 UTC 2019
*broute
:BROUTING ACCEPT

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT
:OUTPUT ACCEPT
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT

*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT
:FORWARD ACCEPT
:OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Trying to load that after saving to a file (e.g., `sudo ebtables-save > tmp.txt && sudo ebtables-restore tmp.txt`) or more directly with

```
sudo ebtables-save | sudo ebtables-restore
```

Always results in:

```
Bad table name 'broute'.
```

And an exit value of `255`.

Why?

**NOTE:** Happens in a number of distros, but this last test was on Ubuntu server 18.04. ebtables v2.0.10-4 (December 2011)

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a confirmed Ubuntu Bug. You can look up more info here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ebtables/+bug/1672276

There is a workaround, I have not tried it myself, So I cannot confirm that it works. You can see the workaround here :https://knoffhoff.tumblr.com/post/59967875099/how-to-save-and-load-ebtables-rules